# what is the difference between `c = Controller(model, view)` and `Controller(model, view)` in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, model-view-controller, instance

I encontered a situation in my code and doubt it.
I have a code like this:

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = View()
    db_name = 'db/main.db'
    model = Model(db_name)
    Controller(model, view)  # Connect the model and the view using the controller
    
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but this wouldn't work as expected.
I did this and it worked:

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = View()
    db_name = 'db/main.db'
    model = Model(db_name)
    c = Controller(model, view)  # Connect the model and the view using the controller
    
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

notice that I am not using the `c` variable. what I don't understand is what is the difference in the code, I am calling the controller and I think it should work, what I am missing here?

I searched it but I want to gain some insight about the internal work of it.

Comment: You need to share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), to get a better answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't affect it to a variable, the "Controller" is destroy
(I guess it's the way Python works)
Here a simple exemple you can run to see the difference:

```
from  PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

class Test():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        print("TEST " + str(self.id) + " => CREATE")

    def __del__(self):
        print("TEST " + str(self.id) + " => DESTROY")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Test(1)
    c = Test(2)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Console output :

```
TEST 1 => CREATE
TEST 1 => DESTROY
TEST 2 => CREATE
```

Comment: So you say that it is all about the garbage collection in Python, thank you.

Comment: Remove the QT stuff and you'll see `TEST 2 => DESTROY` too.